# Hadoop setup on mac machine

Tags: hadoop

Hi I was trying to set up hadoop 2.5.1 on my mac machine. When i did "ssh localhost" I got the "connect to host localhost port 22: connection refused" message.

Has anyone run into similar issue in the past and how did you overcome that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Preferences -> Sharing". Then enable "Remote Login"